# Dates with no year in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to format a set of dates with no year (e.g. "Mar-03") using the following code:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates, format="%d-%b")
```

I have dates of 'Feb-29', which raises a ValueError: "day is out of range for month", since the default year is 1900 which is not a leap year. Is there a way to override the default year in Pandas, or some other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simpliest is add default year, e.g. here `2000`:

```
#03-Mar
dates = pd.to_datetime('2000-' + dates, format="%Y-%d-%b")

#Mar-03
dates = pd.to_datetime('2000-' + dates, format="%Y-%b-%d")
```